# Will my chances of obtaining a student visa in Canada be reduced if I mention I applied for permanent residency?

Tags: international-students, visa

I have been accepted into one of the top 10 engineering universities in Canada. I am starting to fill in the forms for a student visa, but my permanent residency application is still in the pipeline. If I mention this in the form, will my chance of getting a student visa be reduced?

The same form also requires me to mention only one post-secondary degree. Can I mention my bachelor degree instead of Master's? My current program offers me a Master's degree but in completely different field, which is my actual motivation to join the course in Canada.

Comment: Does "PR" here mean "permanent residency"?

Comment: @TomChurch Yeah, PR Visa

Comment: They probably will know about it whether you mention it or not. It is never a good idea to be dishonest on a visa application.

Comment: They will certainly automatically connect your two applications, and whoever reviews your student application will see that you have a PR application. There is no point in concealing it.

Comment: I just did the PR process, canada is VERY organized in this aspect. In fact, they already know that he applied for both. But they also understand your situation. Where exactly is your PR? EE? ITA? On the diplom question, you are overthinking it a bit, IMHO. You got accepted by the university, that's more important. Personally, I'd put the higher, regardless of the field.

Comment: @FábioDias Thanks for your input. My application is still in EE

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is whether you are required to mention your permanent residency on your student visa application. If it is not required, I would refrain from mentioning this issue both in the application and during the interview as temporary residentship (e.g student visa) expects you to plan on returning after the agreed upon period. However, If you are required to provide such information in the form or are asked about in the interview, I would STRONGLY encourage you to provide the honest answer. Being dishonest in your application or interview can easily lead to your Visa being rejected. Bear in mind that your residency application is an officially submitted document and can easily be recovered if the Visa administration office seeks to look for it.